# How to get top most liked post among my all post from mysql using PHP

Tags: php

As per the below code `status='notlove'` shows that the user already liked, and `status='love'` indicated that user liked it and again unlike this post,
The Qus is, the code gives me the proper result but when i liked a new post, 
it is not showing me the proper result, instead of showing most liked post it is showing me the New Post result, How can i solve this Issue?

Kindly refer my Table View also

[image]

I'm getting the user which is logged in

```
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
//query for getting the top most timeline id of current log in  user
$sql= "SELECT * 
        FROM lovetimeline 
            INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT userId, MAX(timelineId) AS Maxscore 
                        FROM lovetimeline 
                        GROUP BY userId
                      ) topscore 
            ON lovetimeline.ownerId = '$id' 
            AND status='notlove' 
            AND lovetimeline.timelineId = topscore.maxscore";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //getting the top liked post from table
    $_SESSION["toppost"] = $row["timelineId"];
}
```

Comment: pls do add the database tables and explain better

Comment: inner join should be between 2 tables what it means ? topscore ON lovetimeline.ownerId = '$id' ? why $id?  it must be like lovetimeline.ownerId = topscore.ownerId & also you need to select ownderId for subquery part tooo

Comment: Thank you Sayed Mohd Ali Sir for the help